# Converting daily data to six-hourly

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file containing daily data with the following format:

```
Year  Month  Day  RR
1979    4   14  6.4
1979    4   15  1
```

I want to create six hourly data for this with the following format:

```
Year  Month  Day HH  RR
1979    4   14   00   1.6
1979    4   14   06   1.6
1979    4   14   12   1.6
1979    4   14   18   1.6
1979    4   15   00   0.25
1979    4   15   06   0.25
1979    4   15   12   0.25
1979    4   15   18   0.25
```

I want to create an "HH" column containing the 6hourly intervals (0,6,12,18) and divide the "RR" value by 4.

Any suggestion on how to do this in R in the simplest way?

As of now, I am doing manually in excel but I am processing 30 years of daily data.

I'll appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok.Thank you..I jest edited the question.

Comment: So this? `df1 <- df[rep(rownames(df), each = 4),]; df1$RR <- df1$RR/4`

Comment: @Sotos, how can I add the 6 hourly interval? your method works!

Comment: Hard Code it? It's always going to be `0, 6, 12, 18` right?

Comment: Expanding @Sotos comment: `df1 <- data.frame(df1, HH = rep(c(0,6,12,18), length(df1[,1])/4) )` should work. If you don't want to start with 0 value you can just define `HH` outside, make sure it is same length removing first `n` values

Comment: @JānisGredzens You don't even need to `rep`. R recycles, so this `data.frame(df1, HH = c(0, 6, 12, 18))` will do the job